# Attribute href not allowed on element input at this point

Tags: html

I know my code is invalid (fails HTML5 validation checker) and the reason why - is there any simple way to validate this without changing the other attributes or starting again?

```
                        <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios2" value="option2" data-toggle="collapse" href="#card">PayPal / Maestro</label>

                        <div id="card" class="accordion-body collapse in">
```

The href="#card" triggers an event that collapses an accordion. Yes it works, and WC3 validation is a guide... but what the hey

Comment: Can't you simply use `data-href` instead like you did with `data-toggle`?

Comment: No that does not work :( Here is the fiddle, line 57,  http://jsfiddle.net/Jwkbv/)

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this

```
<input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios2" value="option2" data-toggle="collapse" onfocus="doSomething();"/>

function doSomething(){
  //do what you want to do here
}
```